# Autorun removable drive

Tags: autoit, usb-drive, autorun

Autorun was disabled in Windows. I am looking for an alternative. I got this AutoIt script :

```
 $DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = "0x00008000"
 $WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219

 GUICreate("")
 GUIRegisterMsg($WM_DEVICECHANGE , "MyFunc")

 Func MyFunc($hWndGUI, $MsgID, $WParam, $LParam)
      If $WParam == $DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL Then
           MsgBox(4096, "Info", "My Drive has been Inserted, Backup My Files!")
      EndIf
 EndFunc

 While 1
      $GuiMsg = GUIGetMsg()
 WEnd
```

Soon as plugged in, the message box appeared. Now, to run a file I replaced

```
MsgBox(4096, "Info", "My Drive has been Inserted, Backup My Files!")
```

by

```
Run ("F:\path\to\my\file.cmd")
```

But what to change so `file.cmd` can be run on computers that assign a drive letter different than `F:`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autoit script to run when USB is mounted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252893/autoit-script-to-run-when-usb-is-mounted)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for some WAVE-files on a Removable Device (SD-Card) with this code:

```
#include <Array.au3>

; Register search function
Global $DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = "0x00008000"
Global $WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219
Global $drives = DriveGetDrive("REMOVABLE")
GUIRegisterMsg($WM_DEVICECHANGE, "searchOnSD")

; check all already known removable devices
If UBound($drives) > 0 Then
    For $drive In $drives
        If StringRegExp($drive, "^[[:alpha:]]:$") Then check($drive)
    Next
EndIf

; search for WAV-file on SD-Card
Func searchOnSD($hWndGUI, $MsgID, $WParam, $LParam)
    If $WParam == $DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL Then
        $newDrives = DriveGetDrive("REMOVABLE")
        $drive = $newDrives
        For $i = 0 To UBound($drives) - 2
            _ArrayDelete($drive, 0)
        Next
        If UBound($drive) > 0 Then
            $drive = $drive[0]
            If StringRegExp($drive, "^[[:alpha:]]:$") Then
                ConsoleWrite("new removable (" & $drive & ") found." & @CR)
                check($drive)
            EndIf
        EndIf
    EndIf
    $drives = DriveGetDrive("REMOVABLE")
EndFunc   ;==>searchOnSD
```

In the `check($drive)` function I then performed something with the WAVE file after evaluating `DriveStatus($drive) == "READY" And FileExists($wavFile)`.