# Run when USB is mounted

Tags: autoit, usb-drive, autorun

Microsoft disabled autorun. However to run a scan and backup files (defined in `file.cmd`), I found this AutoIt script:

```
$DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = "0x00008000"
$WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219
GUICreate("")
GUIRegisterMsg($WM_DEVICECHANGE , "MyFunc")

Func MyFunc($hWndGUI, $MsgID, $WParam, $LParam)
   If $WParam == $DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL Then
      MsgBox(4096, "Info", "My Drive has been Inserted, Backup My Files!")
   EndIf
EndFunc

While 1
   $GuiMsg = GUIGetMsg()
WEnd
```

It displays a message box whenever the USB drive, on which the script is, gets plugged in. I compiled and copied it to my USB drive. Soon as I plugged it in, the `MsgBox()` appeared.

I replaced:

`MsgBox(4096, "Info", "My Drive has been Inserted, Backup My Files!")`

with:

`Run ("F:\path\to\my\file.cmd")`.

But other computers assign a different drive letter to the USB drive. How can I edit the script so running `file.cmd` doesn't require the drive letter `F:` assigned? I am completely OK if someone can translate this into Python.

Answer (score 0):

> You will need to cycle thru all removable drives and search for the
>   file you need to run.

```
$DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = "0x00008000"
$WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219

GUICreate("")
GUIRegisterMsg($WM_DEVICECHANGE , "MyFunc")


While True
    $GuiMsg = GUIGetMsg()
WEnd


Func MyFunc($hWndGUI, $MsgID, $WParam, $LParam)

    If $WParam == $DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL Then

        $Drives = DriveGetDrive( "REMOVABLE" )
        For $i = 1 to $Drives[0]
            $file = $Drives[$i] & "\path\to\my\file.cmd"
            If FileExists($file) Then Run($file)
        Next

    EndIf

EndFunc
```